# Reading DDB records for migration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have DDB with 1.4m records in it. For a particular migration I need the primary key of all records in table.

I can export only 100 records at one time in excel from export to csv option. I can create an AWS Data Pipeline but that is a costly operation. I can write a script to scan entire DDB and get all keys.

What are other possible ways?

Comment: A script is definitely going to be the cheapest way and will likely require the least setup. You can write a NodeJS or Python script to do the scan in probably 50 lines of code or less. You could also probably script CLI calls too. And 1.4MM items is not too much so you can expect your scan to complete in a matter of a couple of minutes. Definitely under 5 as long as you have enough capacity on the table. If not, it may take a bit longer if you don’t want to max out the read capacity.

Comment: Thanks Mike Dinescu :)